What seminary is DA Carson referring to in this remark from Exegetical Fallacies?
I'm wondering if anyone could shed some light on a remark by evangelical biblical scholar D.A. Carson in his book Exegetical Fallacies (1984): "One well-known seminary insists that proper exegetical method will guarantee such a high quality of exegesis that historical theology may be safely ignored. I can think of no better way of cultivating the soil that sprouts either heresy or the shallowest sort of traditionalism" (p. 137).
Elsewhere in this paragraph he refers to Zane C. Hodges, an alumni and professor at Dallas Theological Seminary. Is that the seminary Carson is likely referring to?
God bless!
Daniel

Interesting quote to say the least.  Historical theology is making a come back and ignoring it comes with peril as D.A. Carson noted.  But I'm wondering whether this Q is a better fit for Christianity.SE.  If your Q is ever closed here, please ask it there.  Hopefully, either community welcomes this important question.

I agree with @GratefulDisciple that SEBH is not the right place; migration would be best, not closing (if that's possible).  The post is fascinating, if not provocative.  I'm certainly interested in more of the context of both Carson's statement and what he refers to.  Technically, if by "proper exegetical method" it means "perfect exegetical method", then perfect theology should be the result.  But, that implies that in the future that theology would be historical.  Carson appears to be saying that the statement encourages divisiveness.  And that's a good point! I doubt it's Dallas.

Agree with @MikeSangrey that the seminary is unlikely to be DTS.  John McArthur's Masters Seminary is a more likely candidate, but I'm heavily speculating here.  What are also safe to exclude from this list are Regent (Vancouver), Fuller & Talbot (southern California), Wheaton (Illinois), WTS (Pennsylvania), TEDS (Illinois), and the the top 7 out of this top 10 list in the USA.  A good benchmark is how much they are a Biblicist.

If it's helpful to people:  The quote is from page 129 in the 1998 edition of Carson's work (different edition from the OP).  And, Carson, in that paragraph, does criticize Hodges exegetical method quite strongly.  And does so in a way that shows a clear logical contradiction between Hodges and the position of "...a proper exegetical method" statement.  It's not surprising that Carson would use logic to support his point.

Fuller quotes from Exegetical Fallacies
Here's the fuller paragraph quote from the final paragraph of the chapter titled "Presuppositional and Historical Fallacies" (emphasis mine) located in the final paragraph of the chapter (1st ed, 1984):

But if we sometimes read our own theology into the text,
the solution is not to retreat to an attempted neutrality, to
try to make one’s mind a tabula rasa so we may listen to
the text without bias. It cannot be done, and it is a fallacy
to think it can be. We must rather discern what our prejudices
are and make allowances for them; and meanwhile
we should learn all the historical theology we can. One
well-known seminary insists that proper exegetical method
will guarantee such a high quality of exegesis that historical
theology may be safely ignored. I can think of no better
way of cultivating the soil that sprouts either heresy or the
shallowest sort of traditionalism. Perhaps one of the most
intriguing-and disturbing-features of Zane C. Hodges’s
20 book to which reference has already been made, is that
to the best of my knowledge not one significant interpreter
of Scripture in the entire history of the church has held to
Hodges’s interpretation of the passages he treats. That does
not necessarily mean Hodges is wrong; but it certainly
means he is probably wrong, and it probably means he has
not reflected seriously enough on the array of fallacies connected
with distanciation.
20 Zane C. Hodges, The Gospel under Siege: A Study of Faith and Works (Dallas: Redención Villa, 1981).

In the 2nd edition (1998), the paragraph above has been moved to section 1 titled "Fallacies arising from omission of distanciation in the interpretive process", replacing the final sentence ("That does not necessarily mean Hodges is wrong ...") with this paragraph:

This is not to say there are no other interpreters in the history of the church who have not entertained one kind or another of two-step salvation, or who have not entertained some distinction between accepting Jesus as Savior and accepting Jesus as Lord. But I know no one who pursues this track with the rigor of Hodges, resulting in many, many utterly novel (and, I fear, unconvincing) exegeses. One of the best brief treatments of the issues involved is provided by John Piper.6
6 The Pleasures of God (Portland: Multnomah. 1991), 279-305.

Identifying the seminary
Looking at the current Program Details of DTS's Master of Theology degree, one concentration (out of 24) is Historical Theology:

Students in this concentration will be equipped, through studying the development of the Christian faith, to communicate faithfully the teachings of Scripture in continuity with historic orthodoxy.

While this does not remove all doubt as that the preferred hermeneutical approach they teach their students is ahistorical, being #1 in the top 10 evangelical seminaries in the USA makes DTS (Dallas, TX) unlikely to be out of alignment with other schools in that top 10 that I personally know to appreciate historical theology as one factor to be aware of in exegesis, namely Fuller (Pasadena, CA), Biola (La Mirada, CA), WTS (Glenside, PA), Gordon-Conwell (Hamilton, MA), and TEDS (Deerfield, IL).
One good benchmark to narrow the school D.A. Carson was referring to (out of the dozens) is to assess how Biblicist they are.

Thank you for your answer. I'm wondering what seminary Carson was referring to at the time, not so much whether the current stare of the seminary is vulnerable to this criticism.

@DanielHyland I understand that I didn't provide the answer (a specific seminary) since I don't know.  Just want to contribute the best I can, to (hopefully) help others provide a better answer.  Feel free to leave this question open (i.e. not accepting any answer) until one arrives.  I see some questions remains open for years.
